# Double quotes inside html from no where displaying white space

Tags: php, html

it might be a stupid question but i struggle with finding the source of my problem.I have a white space from no where, pages are saved as utf-8 and my php/html adds some double quotes that generates me white space. If someone can help me with this i would be glad:)
Here is the  img
[image]

The problem is between col-md-8 and cold-md-4.First function si the left content, second is the right side.
code: 1st function

```
function arata()
{
global $dbh;
echo'
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="cale"><a href="index.php"> Acasă </a><img src="images/sageata.jpg"><span> Sesiuni de instruire </span> </div>  
    <div id="title_page"><h2>Sesiuni de instruire</h2></div>
    <div id="continut">

    <div class="box box-solid">

                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="box-group" id="accordion">
                                        <!-- we are adding the .panel class so bootstrap.js collapse plugin detects it -->
                                        ';
                                        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Sesiune order by ID_Sesiune desc"); 
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
                                    {   
                                $id_sesiune=$row['ID_Sesiune'];
                                $titlu=$row['Titlu'];
                                $desc=$row['Descriere'];
                                      echo'  <div class="panel box box-primary">
                                            <div class="box-header">
                                                <h4 class="box-title">
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#'.$id_sesiune.'">
                                                       '.$titlu.'
                                                    </a>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="'.$id_sesiune.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="box-body">
                                                    '.$desc.'   
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>';
                                       } 
                                  echo'  </div>
                                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                            </div><!-- /.box -->
    </div></div>';
}
```

code: 2nd function

```
function Stiri()
{
global $dbh;
echo'
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="inscrie"><button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary2" data-toggle="button">Click aici pentru înscriere<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button></div>
    <div id="search">   
    <div class="input-group">
    <form method="GET" class="cauta" action="cautare.php">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cautare" placeholder="Caută în site ...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </span>
      </form>
    </div></div>
    <div id="noutati">
    <h2>Noutăţi</h2>
    <ul>';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Noutati order by Data desc limit 7"); 
                $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {   
            echo '<li><a href="noutati.php?id='.$row['ID_Noutati'].'">'.$row['Titlu'].'</a></li>';
            }
    echo'</ul>
    <div id="toate"><a href="noutati.php"><button type="button" class="btn3 btn-primary3">Toate noutăţile</button></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: We also need your source code to provide some valuable help.

Comment: yep, i'm using bootstrap

Comment: Do as @Bonatoc said and use trim function in php while display values

Comment: I was wondering if it has to do with PHP or bootstrap, anyway, as @gunaseelan said, using trim will pretty much solve your problem (apart from the `"`, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
───→</div>↲
───→<div class="col-md-4">...
```

With `↲` being a new line, and `───→` being a tab. You have space! The "quotes" you see are the DOM inspector saying "here's a text node", they're not in the source. All that's in your source, is the whitespace that you put there.

Try:

```
</div><div class="col-md-4">...
```

Comment: fixed it, it was like u said from the `echo'
    <div class="col-md-4">` col md 4 was on a different lane, thnx alot